# Android Google Maps InfoWindow not resizing properly

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I have a custom info window set up for my marker with simple 9patch file for its background. It seems to be working perfectly but when I run the app on emulator (Nexus 6P) it is misaligned - left side of 9patch ends up being shorter then the right side. You can see what I am talking about on this picture:

[image: misaligned]

As you can see on the photo, left size is larger and therefore info windows seems of center. This happens is emulator but on my Galaxy S6 everything appears normal. I am not sure if it is the emulator or pixel density problem.

I also don't think its problem with 9patch since in preview everything seems to be normal.

[image: preview]

Also in XML layotu where I use the background, preview shows normally sized info window.

Comment: Ever figure this out? If so care to share your 9 patch file?

Comment: Sorry, I never figured it out in the end.

Comment: can you share the 9 pach file with us ?